# If else in validates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In model I want something like below

```
validates :category, :presence => true if self.post = "this_is_post"
```

Is it possible or I have to use a hook method before save for this checking?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
validates :category, :presence => true, :if => ->(a){ a.post == 'this_is_post' }
```

Comment: could you please explain what is a here. In model I use self.post to access any resource field.

Comment: @user3128796 if you pass `Proc` object in this `:if` options, it is evaluated with your model object passed into it (it's referenced with `a` in my example). So you can simply call on it `post`, like you would with 'regular' object.

Answer (score 0):

Here, more than one code  snippest for validate condition in rails:

```
 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :surname, presence: true, if: "name.nil?"
 end
```

========================

```
validates :category,
        :presence => true,   
        :if => :valid?

 def valid?
    self.post == "this_is_post"
 end
```

================

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :category, presence: true, if: "self.post.eql?('this_is_post')"
 end
```

Comment: last one is not working but I am looking something like the last one